# How does an architecture do atomic swap?

Tags: assembly, architecture, atomic, clock

Regardless of the architecture implementing it, an atomic swap assembly instruction must take multiple clock cycles as it accesses RAM.

How do architectures generally guarantee that a thread doesn't get interrupted (by the clock or some other I/O device) while executing the instruction, between reading the memory and placing its contents in a register?

Comment: Why does it necessarily access RAM? Also, RAM accesses don't take just multiple clock cycles, they take dozens-hundreds of them.

Comment: I wanted to list a specific memory, I assume for any other type the process is the same. I meant multiple as > 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the processor side an instruction wont get interrupted or re-arranged such that functionally the to and from  are correct.  On the memory controller side there must be an indication on the memory bus that this is an atomic access, not necessarily using that term, then the memory controller must insure that for that location there is nothing that happens between the read and write.  The memory controller is free to mix in other operations so long as they dont affect the atomic operation.  Instead it may be implemented on the processor side, the processor may insure that no operations happen, for that location, between the read and write, then the memory controller can be less smart.

Folks that sell processor IP like ARM and MIPS will have documentation you can download.  You can also look at processors like the openrisc which I believe uses a wishbone interface and see how they implemented it (assuming they have an atomic swap instruction).

Comment: If this were to be done by the processor(guarantee that no other core accesses memory), wouldn't it be inconsistent with the fact that a core can't disable interrupts for other cores? My point is that in one instance one core is allowed to influence the actions of the others, while in another instance it's not allowed.

Comment: single or multi it is not any accesses it is any accesses to that location other cores can certainly perform accesses and the core doing a swap can queue up an interrupt access either in parallel or get in line behind the swap.

Comment: arms multicore solution is to replace the single swap instruction and replace it with a pair of special instructions one for the load one for the store, that way the memory controller for the ram shared by all cores is not blocked by an atomic, the memory controller keeps track of the exclusive accesses if a location has an exclusive read from one core then another core does any access before that first core does its exclusive write the write fails and the software tries the read/write again until it can complete both with no interference.

Comment: using an atomic wherever in the memory path, you can either block everything until that access completes or you can let things get out of order.  Being the same ram at the same speed it is not like an interrupt fetch is going to be drastically affected by waiting on the atomic to complete.  the series of caches and cache line fetches are going to overshadow the completion of the atomic

Comment: Talking about arm devices, do the TI arm and dps processors have atomic instructions?

Comment: that is a wide open question with the number of ARM based processors TI makes, but in general yes, the swp instruction is still there.  there is a coprocessor register you can check to insure the register is supported by that core AFAIK.  and the ldrex/strex instruction pair will be there for the newer multi-core processors